# Проблема с конвертацией символов в джанго

Tags: python, django

как сконвертировать символы такого вида %22 %22 в " "? с помощью питона или джанго

Comment: `urllib.parse.unquote()`

Comment: @D.Violet Это работает только с новыми строками, а то что было уже сохранено он не обрабатывает

Comment: вы не привели в вопросе свои попытки и данные уточнения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from urllib.parse import unquote
url = 'example.com?title=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0'
unquote(url)
```

---

=  'example.com?title=правовая+защита'